# why regexp.FindAllString return matched results with unwanted empty strings?

Tags: regex, go

there is the regexp expression :

```
302\=.+?190\=(\d|\.)+|`
```

and this is the string be matched:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=181|35=i|34=6|49=XCD1|52=20171025-08:33:56.791|56=Q142|296=3|302=5|295=1|299=0|188=0.74499|190=0.74549|302=4|295=1|299=0|188=0.74996|190=0.75026|302=3|295=1|299=0|188=88.751|190=88.801|10=022|
```

the result should be:

```
302=5|295=1|299=0|188=0.74499|190=0.74549
302=4|295=1|299=0|188=0.74996|190=0.75026
302=3|295=1|299=0|188=88.751|190=88.801
```

be it return results with some empty strings:

```
[]string{"",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       "302=5|295=1|299=0|188=0.74499|190=0.74549",
       "302=4|295=1|299=0|188=0.74996|190=0.75026",
       "302=3|295=1|299=0|188=88.751|190=88.801",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       "",
       ""
       ....
}
```

the code is below:

```
string := `8=FIX.4.4|9=181|35=i|34=6|49=XCD1|52=20171025-08:33:56.791|56=Q142|296=3|302=5|295=1|299=0|188=0.74499|190=0.74549|302=4|295=1|299=0|188=0.74996|190=0.75026|302=3|295=1|299=0|188=88.751|190=88.801|10=022|`
re := regexp.MustCompile(`302\=.+?190\=(\d|\.)+|`)
re.FindAllString(a1, -1)
```

you can try it on: https://play.golang.org/p/0x_lBAX6Vk

Comment: `(\d|\.)` --- this might be improved with `[\d.]`. Also `=` should not be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the trailing `|`.

`xxx|` expression means - `xxx` **OR** an empty string.

You should escape it so that it was treated literally: `\|`.